# MySQL не работает рабочий SQL запрос в теле триггера

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть две таблицы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

cdr - локальная таблица на движке FEDERATED, то есть данные получает с удаленного сервера из аналогичной по структуре таблицы. Хранит много инфы о вызовах на офисную АТС, но нужно выдергивать определенные номера и заносить их в отдельную таблицу.

В MySQL Workbench в разделе редактирования таблицы добавляю триггер

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER dials_insert AFTER INSERT ON calllist.cdr FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

INSERT INTO calllist.dials (dials.CID, dials.calldate)

SELECT src, calldate FROM calllist.cdr WHERE calldate = (SELECT MAX(calldate) FROM calllist.cdr);

END
```

После совершения звонка в cdr появляется запись, в dials запись не добавляется, однако если тело скрипта выполнить в среде Workbench как скрипт то в dials запись попадет, код рабочий.

Сервер 5.7.11

Comment: Странно почему он дает создавать триггер. Мне казалось, что к federated идет обращение только когда работает запрос. Т.е. удаленная БД где физически лежит таблица не сообщает сама об изменениях на локальную

Comment: Не сообщает - верно, однако мне казалось локальная таблица изменения сама должна заметить и вызвать триггер. нет?

Comment: Я точно не знаю, с mysql и такими особенностями не сталкивался, но логика мне подсказывает, что удаленный сервер сообщать не будет. Это же не репликация, удаленный сервер без запроса локального скорее всего ничего делать не будет

Comment: Кстати, как вариант, в большинстве случаев в триггере на eath row нельзя читать таблицу на которую сам триггер.

Comment: Вот это уже интересно, спасибо, разберу этот вопрос подробнее